# Converting ONLY first letter of string to upper case MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, formatting

I have an entry form where I am entering first and last names and want to convert the first letter of each to upper case. I have been using:

```
Private Sub FirstName_AfterUpdate()

Me.FirstName*= StrConv(Me.FirstName, vbProperCase)

End Sub
```

However some of the last names have a capital in the middle (e.g McDonald) and the code above converts all the other letters to lowercase. Is there a way where the first letter can be capitalised without affecting the other letters?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no intrinsic function. Have to build your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string manipulation functions to break up and rebuild string, like:

`StrConv(Left(LastName, 1), vbUpperCase) & Mid(LastName, 2)`